# Finding the first and last row numbers from a range variable

Tags: excel, vba, range

I have some code I'm working with that has excel ranges saved in variables.  I need a way to find the first and the last rows of these range variables.  I prefer not to use the `xlend(down).row` method if at all possible.  I guess I could put it into an array and get the lbound and ubound values, but that seems like a lot of work for a pretty simple task.  Any simple solutions to the problem?

This is what I have as an example:

```
sub test()
dim r as range
dim x as integer
dim y as integer

set r as worksheets("sheet1").Range("A1:A7")
x = r.row 'This gets the first row in the range.
y = r.lastrow 'this isn't valid, but I need something that will do the equivalent of this pseudo code
end sub
```

Comment: `r.cells(1).Row` and `r.cells(r.cells.count).row`  assuming a rectangular single-area range

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this

```
y = r.rows.count + x -1
```